# Is a mongodb build that uses the -ssl option vulnerable to heartbleed?

Tags: openssl, heartbleed, mongodb

If one is using MongoDB enterprise, or built MongoDB from source using the -ssl option (as described [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/)), is that MongoDB vulnerable to the [heartbleed](http://heartbleed.com/) bug?

I know mongo needed openssl-devel to be installed on the machine for the build to work. But is it now using that vulnerable openssl version internally and now mongoDB needs to be entirely rebuilt or updated? Or if you update openssl on the server that is sufficient?

Comment: If the build was static, rebuild needed. If shared library was used, disconnect from Web, update from your build rig, reboot, reissue certs, restart.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I know if the build was static or not? I built mongo using the -ssl flag, eg `scons -j 8 --ssl --64 all`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this (not just *MongoDB*, but any program) is quite system dependent.

If you are running MongoDB with SSL enabled at compile time, *and* enabled at run-time, *and* it's using a vulnerable OpenSSL (1.0.1—1.0.1f with hearbeat not explicitly removed), then *yes*.

If you are only listening on localhost, or you have packet filtering/firewalling to allow only trusted clients you are less at risk, but you are still *vulnerable* of course.

OpenSSL provides two libraries, `libssl` and `libcrypto`, MongoDB uses both (this flaw is contained only in `libssl`). If OpenSSL is *dynamically* linked in, you should be able to just update OpenSSL and restart the affected processes. If it is *statically* linked in, you need to update OpenSSL, *rebuild* the affected software, stop all affected daemons/processes, reinstall, then restart them. Whether you upgrade to 1.0.1g, or a patched 1.0.1(≤f) with the problem feature disabled, see below for steps to confirm that you've properly updated.
Then [get busy picking up the pieces](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55075/does-heartbleed-mean-new-certificates-for-every-ssl-server) if you have untrusted users/connections.

On most *nix systems you can run `ldd` against the binaries, this will confirm if OpenSSL (i.e. `libssl.so`) is dynamically linked. This only proves a binary uses OpenSSL, no dynamic dependency does not always mean it does not use OpenSSL: it may be static, loaded by a different dependent library, or even loaded on-demand (e.g. Apache `httpd` loading `mod_ssl.so`). `mongod` links directly against OpenSSL though..

An alternate approach to `ldd` which may be more reliable:

- determine the process PID(s) then as root, run `lsof -p PID` or `lsof -p PID1,PID2,...` to see if it has the library open
- on Linux you can instead `cat /proc/PID/maps` and check which libraries are mapped in

The above *only* work when a dynamic library (`libssl.so`) is used, if the static library (`libssl.a`) was used the code is present directly in the binaries, not loaded from an external library (which makes it harder to upgrade of course, most systems use dynamic OpenSSL libraries partly for this reason).

Some software (I wish they all did), tells you what build and run-time features/libs they use, by way of logging at startup or with verbose/debug/version/help command line options. For MongoDB use  `mongodb --version` for this. In 2.6, this calls the API function `SSLeay_version()`, so it will correctly show the run-time (not the build-time) version of OpenSSL, *but* it doesn't tell you if it's statically or dynamically linked. In the case of Mongodb, you know OpenSSL is enabled, and since the  `mongodb` excutable is directly linked against the SSL libraries, `ldd` will tell you if they're dynamically linked or not.

In other cases, you might be stuck with something unpretty to try and determine what library version might be statically linked: `strings -a` or `objdump -s`.

---

MongoDB provides an SSL/TLS TCP service when SSL is enabled, check if it's listening on anything other than localhost via `netstat`, or by attempting a connection (probably port 27017). The `lsof` output also shows listening ports, or try `lsof -p $PID -a -i tcp` for just TCP (note MongoDB doesn't run TLS on a distinct port).

If you have a recent(-ish) `nmap` you can use its `mongodb-info` script:

```
$ nmap -vvv -sV --version-all --script mongodb-info.nse -p 27017 localhost
[...]
PORT      STATE SERVICE VERSION
27017/tcp open  mongodb MongoDB 2.6.0
| mongodb-info: 
[...]
|     compilerFlags = -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -fPIC -fno-strict-\
        aliasing -ggdb -pthread -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Winvalid-\
        pch -pipe -O3 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fno-builtin-\
        memcmp
|     loaderFlags = -fPIC -pthread -Wl,-z,now -rdynamic
|     debug = false
|     version = 2.6.0
|     OpenSSLVersion = OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
[...]
```

You can also probe for the problematic TLS extension with OpenSSL's `s_client`, *though take care to use a recent version which sends a TLS client hello and has the heartbeat extension enabled*, an SSL2 client hello *will not* enable the extension, nor will a client without heartbeat support:

```
echo Q | openssl s_client -connect myhost:27017 -tls1 -tlsextdebug
```

This works regardless of the SSL connection preference you are using for MongoDB.

The server extensions will be listed within the first few lines of output, before certificate details:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
TLS server extension "renegotiation info" (id=65281), len=1
0001 - <SPACES/NULS>
TLS server extension "session ticket" (id=35), len=0
TLS server extension "heartbeat" (id=15), len=1
[...]
```

This alone doesn't prove you are vulnerable, or that you are running OpenSSL, or even a specific OpenSSL version. If you like living dangerously, you may wish to attempt to use one of the POC scripts. (I've used [`ssltest.py`](https://github.com/musalbas/heartbleed-masstest/blob/master/ssltest.py) successfully, and without crashing Apache httpd or mongod processes, YMMV.)

To check your OpenSSL version and options use `openssl version -a`, the presence of `-DOPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS` indicates the problematic feature has been disabled at build time. There's no guarantee that the `openssl` command will use the same library as anything else, to really check thoroughly you should identify all likely libraries:

```
find / -name "libssl.*"
```

The default behaviour (gcc+binutils) when searching for libraries is "first found" honoring the library directory ordering, when both dynamic and static versions of libraries found together it prefers dynamic libraries (unless `-static` is used, this isn't an option with MongoDB since it's implemented in C++). Even if `libssl.so` is present OpenSSL *could* still be statically linked, though for a normal build with `libssl.so` available, it will dynamic not be static (the MongoDB SCons build makes no special attempt to use `libssl.a`).

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! 

Using `ldd` I see:
`libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f4febfd7000)`
and using `cat proc/PID/maps` I see:
`7fec227c8000-7fec22829000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 262873                     /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e`

I've [patched](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2014-April/020249.html) and restarted everything so I think I'm good. 

Thanks again!